# Is there a way for a python turtle color being always the reverse color of the point the turtle is in?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want the turtle to apply the inverse color effect wherever it passes. For example if the turtle pass through a red point, i want it to draw blue on it and vice-versa. I would be even more grateful if the solution also work with the fill command.

Comment: It's the `penreverse` command in some dialects, but the built-in module doesn't support it.